# Angular2 template html loop array to return true of false

Tags: arrays, angular, angular2-template

Example:

I have the following Object:

```
{
  "Person": {
    "Name": {},
    "Hobbies": {
      "0": {
        "Description:Soccer": {},
        "IsActive:false": {}
      },
      "1": {
        "Description:Hockey": {},
        "IsActive:false": {}
      },
      "2": {
        "Description:Tennis": {},
        "IsActive:true": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to loop through the array and check wether any hobby is active.
If so it should return true, and display an image.

```
<img [src]="Person.Hobbies != null ? './images/hobby.png' : ''"/>
```

I would like the image to only show one time.

Is that possible using html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop with ngFor, to show all in array.

```
<img [src]='./images/hobby.png' *ngFor="let hobby in Person.Hobbies"> </img >
```

then add an ngIf condition for each hobby in the list if there's any specific reason you only want to show a subset.

Example

```
<div *ngFor="let hobby in Person.Hobbies">
  <img *ngIf="hobby.IsActive"  [src]='./images/hobby.png'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would set a property in your Component

```
<img *ngIf="showHobbyImg">

this.showHobbyImg = false;

const hobbies = this.person.Person.Hobbies;
for (key in hobbies) {
  if (hobbies["IsActive:true"]) {
    this.showHobbyImg = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

If you're using lodash you could simplify this a bit:

```
this.showHobbyImg = _.some(this.person.Person.Hobbies, ['IsActive:true', {}]);
```